# Regex is working in regex101.com but not in google scripts

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

## The problem:

I had a similar problem to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411669/google-app-script-regex-exec-returns-null-only-in-one-function) - my Regex works like a charm in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/inpP9O/4), but returns null in google scripts.

I'm trying to return the next line on a number of items:

- Confirmation code
- Check-in
- Checout
- Payout
- Number of Guest
- Payout

## Here is the data I am searching in:

New booking confirmed!
Jake arrives Oct 22

Send a message to confirm check-in details or welcome Jake.

---

Jake Flake
Phoenix, California, United States
Airbnb member since 2015

Send Jake a message:
https://www.airbnb.com/z/q/;laskdf;lksjdf

---

The Getaway
https://www.airbnb.com/manage-listing/asdflkjsdf;lkajsfd

Trip details
Check-in
Sun, Oct 22
Anytime after 4PM

Checkout
Thu, Oct 26
11AM

Guests
13

Confirmation code
H7XS0SA8
View itinerary
https://www.airbnb.com/reservation/itinerary?code=aasdfasdf

---

Payment
$275.50 x 4 nights
$1102.00
Cleaning Fees
$180.00
Guest Pays
$1282.00
Airbnb Fees
-$38.46
You earn
$1243.54
On the day after your guest checks in, the payment method you supplied will be credited. For details, see your transaction history.
Your guest paid $161.15 in Occupancy Taxes. Airbnb remits these taxes on your behalf.

---

---

Get ready for Jake’s arrival
Provide Directions
Confirm that your guest knows how to get to your place.
Tidy Up
Clean up all shared spaces. Make sure your guest has clean linens and towels.

---

Customer Support

Visit Help Center
https://www.airbnb.com/help?eal_exp=asdfasdf

Contact Airbnb
https://www.airbnb.com/help/contact_us?eal_exp=asdfasdf

Thanks,
The Airbnb Team

Email preferences
https://www.airbnb.com/users/notifications?eal_exp=asdfasdf

Airbnb

## My code that works:

```
function getNumberofGuests(message_body) {
  var num_guests = message_body.match("Guests[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)")[1];
  Logger.log("num_guests: " + num_guests);

  return num_guests;
}
```

Logs -- num_guests: 13

## The same code in a similar senario that doesn't work:

```
function getReservationID(message_body) {
var reservationID = message_body.match("Confirmation\scode[\r\n][^\r\n]+")[1];
  Logger.log("reservationID: " + reservationID);

  return reservationID;
```

Logs -- reservationID: null

### PS

The formatting of the body in this display is off for some reason, and I tried for 30 minutes but still couldn't fix it. In the message_body, it should be a new line after "Check-in", "Checkout", "Guests", "Confirmation code", etc. - there is a new line after every element that is currently showing a space.

I also tried the space character regex, and still got null:

```
 var regExp = new RegExp("Confirmation\scode[\s]^[^\s]+", 'g')
```

Comment: So, `.match(/Confirmation\scode[\r\n][^\r\n]+/)` works, right? Same as `.match(/Confirmation\scode[\r\n]+.+/)`

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the data into a file and then loaded the file into variable dt in the following code:

```
function getMyData() 
{
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
   var dt=myUtilities.loadFile('regex.txt');
   var guests = dt.match(/^Guests (\d+)/m)[1];
   var cf=dt.match(/^Confirmation code ([0-9A-Z]+)/m)[1];
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(dt).append(Utilities.formatString('<br /><strong>Matches:</strong><br />Guests=%s<br />Confirmation Code=%s',guests,cf));
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Input Data & Extracted Parameters');

}
```

After playing with the regexs for a while I got this output which includes a copy of the data:

[image]

(The m flag is for multiline).

#### I missed some of the data the first time around.

Here's the new code with some of your additional parameters:

```
function getMyData() 
{
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
   var dt=myUtilities.loadFile('regex.txt');
   var guests = dt.match(/^Guests (\d+)/m)[1];
   var cf=dt.match(/^Confirmation code ([0-9A-Z]+)/m)[1];
   var chout=dt.match(/^Checkout (.*)$/m)[1];
   var chin=dt.match(/^Trip details (.*)$/m)[1];
   var payout=dt.match(/Guest Pays ([$.0-9]+)/m)[1];
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(dt).append(Utilities.formatString('<br /><strong>Matches:</strong><br />Guests=%s<br />Confirmation Code=%s<br />Checkout=%s<br />Checkin=%s<br />Payout=%s',guests,cf,chout,chin,payout)).setWidth(1200);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Input Data and Extracted Parameters');
}
```

**And here's the output:**

[image]

I'm guessing that you can figure out how to get the rest of them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the code and trying it out, you're getting the null because of what you changed in the match method. The reason why num_guests works is because that it's set up in a way that looks for the word "Guests" and the next line is the result from the array (notice the [1] on the end of the line). That same concept/regex works for the confirmation code portion as well, but you put in the "\s" and changed the order of some parentheses. Since the search code is in double quotes, you don't need the "\s". Basically, you have "Confirmation\scode" when you want "Confirmation code". Although it works in regex101, trying in the Google Apps Script environment will produce actual results.